# Seperate a border/frame from an object using offset i Blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to separate/split the border/edge of this object using an offset edge. Like shown in the first image (done in fusion). The object is curved.

Image 1 is sort of what I'm trying to do. But I need the to parts to follow each others form and have equal thickness around the whole body

[image: This is sort of what I'm trying to do. But I need the to parts to follow each others form and have equal thickness around the whole body]

[image: The object]

[image: The object with border/edge offset split]

[image: The object I want to split]

Comment: In face select mode, ALT-click one of the edges across your edge to select the whole loop, then 'p' to separate it. You might have a problem with the notches though and have to SHIFT-select the faces around them before separating if any are missed. Difficult to tell without seeing the Blend file.

Comment: Thanks! posted an img from blender now. What you're suggesting is close to what I want to do, but I need the separated part to follow the exact form of the outside, so an offset with equal thickness around the object.

Comment: If you want to separate the edge from the centre face it might be easier to diplicate your object and hide the duplicate then select and delete the centre face top and bottom, select the inner edge loops top and bottom and CTRL E > Bridge Edge Loops. Then bring back the duplicate, select top and bottom faces, CTRL I to invert the selection and delete the outer selection. Then you can bridge top and bottom faces.

Answer (score 1):

select the outer face ring

[image]

select more and repeat as long as you need it

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

seperate -> Selection

[image]

[image]

delete unwanted part

[image]

tutorial:

https://youtu.be/PuGHyzvwhWk